# /register java.lang.IllegalStateException: RESTEASY003765: Response is closed

Tags: java, resteasy

This problem is really weird because it happens only in a specific request and everything within it is being executed until the response has to be sent which is considered closed and throws a 500. Also, it works locally, but not on my production environment.

```
@Path("/register")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class RegistrationResource {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final RegistrationDtoMapper registrationDtoMapper;

    @Inject
    RegistrationResource(UserService userService, RegistrationDtoMapper registrationDtoMapper) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.registrationDtoMapper = registrationDtoMapper;
    }

    @POST
    public void register(RegistrationDto dto) {
        RegisterUserCommand registerUserCommand = registrationDtoMapper.dtoToCommand(dto);
        userService.create(registerUserCommand);
    }
}
```

The stack trace is the following :

> 02:21:22.991 [qtp1037955032-28] WARN 
>   o.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel# - /register
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: RESTEASY003765: Response is closed.
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.abortIfClosed(BuiltResponse.java:257)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.abortIfClosed(ClientResponse.java:343)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:75)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.unwrapException(ExceptionHandler.java:128)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:222)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2018:02:21:23 +0000] api - "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 500 4363

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction to understand where resteasy and in what conditions the response is being read twice or closed.

Thanks,

Comment: Is your production environment any different from your development environment? Then you have the culprit, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

It was a synchronous event that was taking more time than expected in production, but never in dev.

Launching the event asynchronously solved the problem.